# How to quickly skip a certain piece of input in C

Tags: c, stdin

For the project I'm building for one of my courses (first time doing this, please don't bash me if I'm missing some basic things), which is basically about handling a data structure, my code should be able to identify if the input is trying to delete an item that's not been previously added to the structure. Thing is, because said input will be given in the form of `function-name item-identifier extra_parameter 1 ... extra_parameter n`, I'll also have to ignore everything that comes after the identifier, to avoid screwing up the next commands. How can I implement this?

An idea I've already came up with is a loop of `scanf("%c")` until we reach \n, or one big `scanf(" %[^\n]")` to save the whole thing in a single array (which I'm also confused over how to make its size scale with how long the rest of the line is), but I find them to be, respectively, slow and heavy

Comment: `fgets` to first read the whole line then `sscanf` may be less error prone.

Comment: Forget about `scanf`, use `fscanf` and then parse the buffer yourself (possibly with `sscanf`). It's hard to impossible to handle incorrect user input with `scanf`.

Comment: I don't understand.  If the item had already been added then you would need to be able to parse the entire line, right? So parse the entire line.  Decide *after* you have read it (all) whether to act on it.  You don't need to special-case the I/O.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip ahead to the next line, you could use `scanf` without a target variable using the assignment-suppressing character `*`:

```c
scanf("%*[^\n]\n");
//      ^
```

Alternatively, use `fgets` to read a full line and then use `sscanf`:

```c
char buf[1024];  // make it large enough for the longest line
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    // successfully read a line
    if (sscanf(buf, "%...", vars...) == expected_number_of_extractions) {
        // successfully extracted all
    }
}
```

---

There are many other ways to parse the needed information from `buf[]` depending on the complexity as noted by David C. Rankin in a comment:

*Walking a pair of pointers, `strtol()/strtoul()/sttrod()` for parsing a sequence of numbers, alternating `strspn()/strcspn()` to read the wanted data and separators, `strtok()` and `strsep()` if empty-fields need to be preserved.*

Comment: That looks like the best "go-to" approach. May also be good to add a sentence there are a number of ways to parse the needed information from `buf[]` depending on the complexity. Walking a pair of pointers, `strtol()`/`strtoul()`/`sttrod()` for parsing a sequence of numbers, Alternating `strspn()`/`strcspn()` to read the wanted data and separators, `strtok()` and `strsep()` if empty-fields need to be preserved. Many ways to *skin-the-parsing-cat* in C.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good point. Added your note to the answer. Thanks!